# How can I select the second element from a group of divs with the same class?

Tags: javascript

I have 4 divs with the same class and I want to select with javaScript only the second one

```
<div class='container'></div>
<div class='container'></div>
<div class='container'></div>
<div class='container'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, you can easily find the CSS selector for any element by inspecting it. For example, in Firefox, right-click the element on the page and click *Inspect Element*. Then in the inspector right-click the element's tag and click *Copy->CSS Selector*. In this case it will give you `div.container:nth-child(2)`. You can then use that directly with `document.querySelector`:

```js
let second = document.querySelector('div.container:nth-child(2)')
console.log(second)
```

```html
<div class='container'>1</div>
<div class='container'>2</div>
<div class='container'>3</div>
<div class='container'>4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can select it with this code: `document.querySelectorAll('.container')[1]` or if they have one parent `document.querySelectorAll('.container:nth-child(2)')`